# Unity: Wait() in Update almost working (But not quite)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, wait

I have a code (C#) with an update function that needs to wait for a few seconds at some point. The problem is that while it is executing the wait command it continues down the update function, resulting in the bit that is supposed to be delayed, to be completely skipped.
Because of the boolean variables the update will only do this stuff once, until I make it available again, so that is no problem.
The code works without the whole waiting thing so don't worry about that, I left out most lines that don't have to do with waiting anyways.

```
void Update()
{

    if (RoundOver == false)
    {
        RoundOver = true;
        Seconds = 3;
        Debug.Log("Waiting", gameObject);
        StartCoroutine(Wait());
        if (Continue)
        {
            Continue = false;
            Debug.Log("Done Waiting", gameObject);
            RoundNumber += 1;                //Just game stuff
            ZombiesLeft = ZombieAmount();    //Just game stuff
            RoundOver = false;
        }
        Debug.Log("Done wit stuff", gameObject);
    }
    if (counter > DelayTime && RoundOver == false)
    {
        counter = 0;
        Debug.Log("Going to spawn a zombie", gameObject);
        SpawnZombie();
    }
    counter += Time.deltaTime;
    }
```

with les wait function:

```
IEnumerator Wait()
{
    Debug.Log("ACTUALLY WAITING", gameObject);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(Seconds);
    Continue = true;
    Debug.Log("ACTUALLY WAITING DONE", gameObject);
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Waiting
ACTUALLY WAITING
Done wit stuff
ACTUALLY WAITING DONE
```

So obviously the right order should be

```
Waiting
ACTUALLY WAITING
ACTUALLY WAITING DONE
Done wit stuff
```

EDIT:
The block in `if (continue)` is supposed to activate the second block when the (here hidden) requirements are met. The second block would keep doing its thing until it is done (could take minutes) and then by setting `RoundOver` to false again re-enabling the first block. The first block is essentially to keep rerunning the second block with increasing variables like `RoundNumber +=1`, and, which is the only problem here, to have the second blocks separated by 3 seconds.

Comment: I have answered your question but It would be nice if you tell us what you want to do because I suspect that It shouldn't go in the Update function

Comment: Updated it in edit

Comment: You could emulate Update with an Enumerator by looping it and ending it with `WaitForEndOfFrame`. So in your Start()-method put StartCoroutine(IEnumeratorUpdate()); and then placing your wait-logic needing code there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around this by turning the `void SpawnZombie()` into an IEnumerator instead of having the separate `Wait()`. I then replaced `SpawnZombie()` with `StartCoroutine(SpawnZombie())`. To make it act like I want it to I added an `if` in the `SpawnZombie()` to make sure the waiting of 3 seconds only occurred when I want it to.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot wait in the `Update` function, you can only wait in a function that returns an `IEnumerator`.

For this you can make something like this

```
void Update()
{
   if (RoundOver == false)
   {
        RoundOver = true;
        StartCoroutine(Wait());
   }
   if (counter > DelayTime && RoundOver == false)
   {
    counter = 0;
    Debug.Log("Going to spawn a zombie", gameObject);
    SpawnZombie();
   }
   counter += Time.deltaTime;
}

IEnumerator Wait()
{
    Seconds = 3;
    Debug.Log("Waiting", gameObject);
    Debug.Log("ACTUALLY WAITING", gameObject);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(Seconds);
    Debug.Log("Done Waiting", gameObject);
    RoundNumber += 1;                //Just game stuff
    ZombiesLeft = ZombieAmount();    //Just game stuff
    RoundOver = false;
    Debug.Log("ACTUALLY WAITING DONE", gameObject);
    Debug.Log("Done wit stuff", gameObject);
}
```

Although this isn't the cleanest of the stuffs, I would remove if possible all the code from Update and start a coroutine when you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your debug statement `Debug.Log("Done wit stuff", gameObject);` is outside of the if statement `if (Continue)`. Because of this, it will display even if the coroutine is still running.

Comment: I get that, the whole point is to have it wait for 3 seconds until continuing down the code.